# Switch to Outlet "Open Hot"

Tags: electrical

Installing a few outlets in my basement. The 2nd of those outlets will be on a switch. I'm running into issues with that 2nd outlet, it has power but isn't working. Using a plug tester it says, "Open Hot". I wired it using 12/2 and honestly I need some help figuring this out. I've tied the neutrals and grounds together in "Box #2" and I'm running the hot to the switch then to the outlet.

See diagram below and ask any questions if needed. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried flipping the switch then testing again?

Comment: When you switch it on does it blow the breaker?  If you tied all the neutrals in box2 together, then 'switch' could cause a dead short.  Typicaly the 'white wire' coming from the switch would look like a neutral, but you would tape it black on both ends, and it would be the switched hot, which would be the only thing connected to the 'outgoing' hot in box2 that feeds outlet2. I would recommend wiring 'outlet2' directly to 'switch' but it's probably too late.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes lmao

Comment: @BillyC. No, doesn't blow the breaker. I'm not following though. So you're saying the switch white should be tied to the box #2 black? What about the switch black?

Comment: Can you add the white wires to the diagram?

Comment: @lemonsevens15 Before I can answer, i need to know how many distinct NM-B (Romex) cables are in box2

Comment: @Mark I've updated the image with a dashed line to represent the white wire. Thanks!

Comment: @BillyC. Three. One from Box #1 (12/2). One from the Switch (12/3). One from Outlet #2 (12/2). Thanks!

Comment: @BillyC. in a switch loop white is reserved for neutral, because all switch loops require neutral now.  Even in conduit where you are not required to pre-wire neutral because it's easily added, the conduit wiring method never allows hot or switched hot to be neutral colors.

Comment: The figure that you have made is incomplete and inconclusive because of that. You claim that the dashed lines represent the white wires and yet show none of that for Box 1 or Outlet 1. You also neglect to show anything at all how things are connected in Box 1 - Those are critical to understanding what is going on. Unless this can be rectified this will need to be closed as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Just want to say this : "it has power but isn't working" - how can an outlet have power but not be working  ? I mean what power doe sit have if ANY since it is not working. Your tester says open hot - which says to me means NO POWER . Unless your neutral is carrying voltage - or you have crossed up your wires..Getting Neutral and Hots mixed up ... Take pictures of what you have at each box and post them - or see my answer to help you troubleshoot it..

Answer (score 2):

1: Do you have power at the switch (Line In) ? [test with a multimeter]

- YES: go to step 2:
- NO : See Answer A:

2: Do you have power at the switch (Line Out) ? [test with a multimeter]

- NO : Flip the Switch and Perform step 2 again.
- YES: Go to step 3
- If after flipping the switch and still no power - the switch is bad.
- Please verify if it is a push type - make sure your insulation is properly peeled back and the wire pushed all the way in.

3: Test inside Box 2 where the wire comes from the switch and goes to the outlet - is your connection there good ?

- Make sure your wire insulation is trimmed.
- Redo and recheck the wire nutting.

4: Check that your outlet wire line in is properly connected to the outlet - if it is a push type - make sure your insulation is properly peeled back and the wire pushed all the way in. (This is probably your issue)

**Answer A:**

You are missing power to the switch; there are two possibilities:

- Box 1 Hot wire from electrical box to box1-box2 wire connection is not properly connected or the insulation has not been removed from the wire when it was wire nutted.
- Box 2 Hot wire connection from box 1 to switch (Line In) is not properly connected or the insulation has not been removed from the wire when it was wire nutted.